# Really Need a Facebook App to post to Facebook Page Wall?

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm using the Facebook API Graph (C# & ASP.NET) to try to dynamically post to a Facebook page I created.

Looking at the code samples floating around.. they suggest creating a Facebook App first (which I have done)..

However..

1. I have 3 different pages I want to post to.. Do I need to create an app for each? (I want to post different things to the 3 pages, not the same posts to each)
2. I just want messages & links to appear as Wall posts. I'm not bothered about having an 'app' that has 'canvas' that is placed in an IFrame.

**Question : So do I still need to write one or more Facebook Apps to post to my 3 different Facebook pages??**

Where I am so far.. I can pass in my apps credentials and get back the access_token. But my posts don't appear to be going anywhere.

I'd rather drop the 'facebook application /canvas' approach if possible If I can post directly to a wall (For the above reasons).

Oh, and before you ask. I don't want to post to my Apps Wall page, I want to post to my other pages (Unless I have to post to my Apps Wall page first?).

I'm sure loads of people have the same questions..

Thanks in advance.

-- Lee

Comment: I wish whoever downvoted the question left some feedback as to why????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create the Facebook App, because that's the only way you'll get the set of API ***keys*** you need for using the API. I think that's the only reason. It's the same when you're using Facebook only for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

- You can do this with only one app
- You'll need these permissions offline_access, publish_stream,
  manage_page
- After "me" request in response you should parse active_tokens of pages
  you administer
- Before you make publish request make sure you set
  "_facebook.active_token" to
  active_token of page where you want
  to publish

Comment: Yes, but do I need to make an app at all?

Answer (score 0):

1 - I have 3 different pages I want to post to.. Do I need to create an app for each?

No because there is an option to allow an single app to handle multiple pages.

2 - I just want messages & links to appear as Wall posts. I'm not bothered about having an 'app' that has 'canvas' that is placed in an IFrame.

You can do that surely with the help of their Graph API.

Comment: Can you give me a little more Umair?

Comment: I should also have mentioned that I want to post different things to the 3 pages (Not the same message appear on each of the 3 pages)

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a canvas, though keep in mind that's where users will go when they click on the name of your app.

Take a look at the Graph API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api, particularly the Publishing section. You want to use `/PROFILE_ID/feed`, where PROFILE_ID is the id of the page you want to post to.

Comment: Yes, but do I need to make an app at all?

Comment: You need to register an app with Facebook to get your app_id and secret, which are needed to use the Graph API.